# JS - Clone a li and if its been already cloned then omit it and modify previous one cloned

Tags: javascript, html

Im doing task history, where you can input which tasks you have done today and, with a button, send them to the "this week" list, where you have a summary of your whole week, and the exact same with "this month".

Clearly i dont want the same task to be copied multiple times, like for ex

```
•Went to the gym
•Coded
•Asked stackOverflow
•Coded
•Asked stackOverflow
```

I want that if a task has been submitted already, then it adds +1 to the total times, and avoid dupping. Following the first example it would look like this:

```
•Went to the gym
•Coded - 2 times
•Asked stackOverflow - 99 times
```

I've been using .cloneNode and .appendChild for the clonning. But now im not quite sure as to how continue with the if conditions to filter duplicates, since the structure of the li is:

```
<li> <p class="taskAdded bodyText"> •Cooked dinner</p> <span class="taskXP favouriteColor">+5xp</span> </li>
```

Comment: How do you persist your data?

Comment: @trincot hey, im new to programming idk what that means! im just building a simple tracker to learn more of the basics. Im having trouble comparing an element that just got created to the elements that were created (with the same method) before.

Comment: The presentation on an HTML page is just that: it is *output* of data. You shouldn't use it as your data store. There is no use to collecting information about a week, a month, if the user must keep their browser open at all times, as otherwise they will lose what they encoded. You'd need to store the things the user selected into some data store, like a database or locally, in a cookie or local storage, ...

Comment: oh i understand what you mean now, yeah i was planning on taking care of that later since now i cant even update the output of the weekly list properly. Once i get the output solved i'll learn how to save information on browser.

Comment: The thing is: when you have your output based on a data structure, the solution will be in that process. So first define your data structure, how you will keep it in memory, and then how you will render that in the HTML document.

Comment: My plan was learning .localStorage on the browser and using that to save the user's lists. How would you solve my question with that in mind? D:

Comment: Maybe first try and then adjust your question.